# Bit Vectors/Bitmaps - объясните как пользоваться данным ресурсом, если можно с примерами

Tags: python-3.x, bitmap

Есть задача на https://www.codewars.com/kata/59f8dd1132b8b9af150001ea/train/python
где нужно применить данный ресурс:

> Описание задания: Растровая карта - это один из способов эффективного
> представления наборов уникальных целых чисел с использованием
> отдельных битов. Чтобы увидеть, как это работает, мы можем
> представлять набор уникальных целых чисел между `0` `<20` с
> использованием вектора/массива 20 бит: `` `var set = [3, 14, 2, 11, 16, 4, 6];` ``  `` `var bitmap = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]; `` `
>
> Как видите, с помощью растрового изображения длина вектора
> представляет диапазон уникальных значений в наборе (в данном случае
> `0-20`), а `0/1` представляет, является ли текущий индекс равным к
> значению в наборе.
>
> Задача:
>
> написать функцию `tobits`, которая примет набор из целых чисел Uniqe и
> выведет бит-вектор/растровый карту используя`1`и`0`для
> представления значений Вход: Функция будет передана набор уникальных
> целых чисел в строковой форме, в случайном порядке, разделенных по
> разрывам линии. Можно ожидать, что каждое целое число будет иметь
> уникальное значение `> = 0` и `<5000`. Ввод будет выглядеть так: `lete anvessInput = '3 \ n14 \ n5 \ n19 \ n18 \ n1 \ n8 \ n11 \ n2 ...'` `
>
> Выход: Ожидается, что функция выведет 5000 -битный вектор (массив)
> битов, либо `0`, или `1`, например: `Let anvessOutput = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, ...]`

Я нашёл в Инете - что можно какому то элементу из представленного набора данных присвоит бит 1 или 0
и по этому биту отслеживать - находится ли данный элемент в наборе или нет
Допустим число 3 "011" - какому нужно биту присвоить 1 или 0 и как это делать

На ресурсе https://redis.io/docs/data-types/bitmaps/ поясняется работа с базой данных "redis"
там описаны команды

```
import redis

r = redis.Redis(decode_responses=True)


res1 = r.setbit("pings:2024-01-01-00:00", 123, 1)
print(res1)  # >>> 0

res2 = r.getbit("pings:2024-01-01-00:00", 123)
print(res2)  # >>> 1

res3 = r.getbit("pings:2024-01-01-00:00", 456)
print(res3)  # >>> 0


r.setbit("pings:2024-01-01-00:00", 123, 1)
res4 = r.bitcount("pings:2024-01-01-00:00")
print(res4)  # >>> 1
```

где показаны примеры использования bitmaps - пример про велосипедистов - отслеживание по присвоенному биту - прошёл ли он промежуточную отметку или нет - 1 значит прошёл 0 - не прошёл
Тоже и на сайт какие посетители из зарегистрированных заходили
А можно ли без базы данных "redis" применять bitmaps
Если можно показать на примере - как устанавливать биты 0 или 1 - допустим на символы из списка
или на цифры
Если можно подскажите какую литературу просмотреть - меня заинтересовала данная задача
На redis.io/docs не так всё понятно.
Как же создать - растровую карту????